# Entity Framework rising error on Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

upon updating a property of an Entity in Entity Framework I receive the error

> The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Now having some google foo I started to google for that problem, however every answer I found did indeed have something to do with code which actually tried to change the Id property of the entity.

I am well aware that I'm not allowed to do it and thus my code doesn't attempt to do it.
Still I'm getting the error.
All the code in question does is read an Entity from the DB and then update a boolean from false to true and then save it back.

This is the code which changes the property:

```
public void ConsumeRequestToken(IOAuthContext requestContext)
        {
            if (requestContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");

            WebApiOAuthRequestToken requestToken = GetRequestToken(requestContext);

            UseUpRequestToken(requestContext, requestToken);

            _requestTokenRepository.SaveToken(requestToken);
        }

static void UseUpRequestToken(IOAuthContext requestContext, WebApiOAuthRequestToken requestToken)
        {
            if (requestToken.UsedUp)
            {
                throw new OAuthException(requestContext, OAuthProblems.TokenRejected,
                                         "The request token has already be consumed.");
            }

            requestToken.UsedUp = true;
        }
```

As you can see I am in no way touching the ID of the Entity.

Does anyone have any idea on why this error is happening? I'm really close on just giving up on it and throwing EF out of the window.

**EDIT**

As requested the _requestRepository.SaveToken() method as well as the underlying UoW Save()

```
public void SaveToken(T token)
        {
            if (_unitOfWork.RepositoryFor<T>().Get(x => x.Token == token.Token).SingleOrDefault() == null)
                _unitOfWork.RepositoryFor<T>().Insert(token);

            _unitOfWork.Save();
        }

public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

**EDIT 2**

_unitOfWork.RepositoryFor().Insert(token):

```
public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
```

**EDIT 3**
Added Stacktrace

```
   at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperty(Int32 ordinal, Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties, Boolean detectOnly)
   at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperties(Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInScalarAndComplexProperties(IList`1 entries)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries(Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.Entries()
   at BackendService.Models.DatabaseContext.SaveChanges() in c:\Work\Backend\Service\Models\DatabaseContext.cs:line 46
```

**EDIT 4**
Added GetAccessToken Method

```
WebApiOAuthRequestToken GetRequestToken(IOAuthContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                return _requestTokenRepository.GetToken(context.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // TODO: log exception
                throw Error.UnknownToken(context, context.Token, exception);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but have you tried inserting a break point just before saving the request token and see what the Id is?

Comment: Like you say, from the code you've included you  shouldn't be getting  that error. What does `_requestTokenRepository.SaveToken` do?

Comment: I edited the question to include the _requestTokenRepository.SaveToken method. @bazz yes I indeed did that and the ID didn't change at all :)

Comment: does anything occur around here in this method: _unitOfWork.RepositoryFor<T>().Insert(token)?

Comment: and the underlying context is the same for both the methods? GetRequestToken and SaveToken?

Comment: @Ric I added the function to the question as well

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: @bazz Yes it *should* be the same Context. I'm using dependency injection for the UnitOfWork. Also added stacktrace :)

Comment: Can you please also add the code for the GetRequestToken()

Comment: @bazz added the method

Comment: That's strange... the only thing I can think of is that the context in ConsumeRequestToken and the one in the Save Method are different 'context' and/or are different 'instances' of the context.

Comment: @bazz You were right, there were multiple DbContext's being created. I added a InSingletonScope() to my ninject binding and now it works like a charm.

Comment: @bazz Please can you add your comments as an answer so it can be accepted...

Comment: @DaveWilliams Comment added as an answer :)

Comment: One thing though. InSingletonScope is not a very smart option for a context. Contexts should be short lived.

Comment: I accepted the answer. Yes InSingletonScope wasn't a wise decision :) I later changed it to be per HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the context in ConsumeRequestToken and the one in the Save Method are different 'context' and/or are different 'instances' of the context